# How to draw a red circle on a JPEG image on android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw circle on an JPEG image which load into my application. When user touch a position, the circle should be drawn on that spot. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific and show that you already tried to actually, well... *do* something. Instead of asking other people to code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919746/draw-circle-where-user-touches-screen)

```
 image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            System.out.println("Touch recieved at "+arg1.getX() + " " + arg1.getY());
            touchX = (arg1.getX());
            touchY = (arg1.getY());

            System.out.println("Touch recieved at "+touchX + " " + touchY);
            image.setImageBitmap(createImage());

            return true;
        }
    });


public Bitmap createImage(){
        Bitmap image = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);


         touchX=touchX- image.getWidth() / 2;
         touchY=touchY- image.getHeight() / 2;

        canvas.drawCircle(touchX, touchY, radius, paint);
        System.out.println("Drew a circle at "+touchX+" " + touchY+" with a radius of "+radius+".");
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: soRry, Sam I misplaced that line as same name "image"