# Android add circle to user clicks

Tags: android, image

I have an image in android which is clickable like so:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/theImage"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Now I want to make some kind of gesture when the user clicks the image. I want the user to see that he clicked the image so I want to make something like, each time th euser clicks the image, then a red small circle shows up on the place where the user clicked and then it fades out.

is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276727/how-to-draw-a-red-circle-on-a-jpeg-image-on-android

Comment: @Zaki this one is very old and missing a lot of data...

Answer (score 0):

Better use ImageButton instead of imageView and set background attribute `?attr/selectableItemBackground`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/theImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@mipmap/theImage_icon"
        />
```

Comment: You can use the same structure with imageView also,
only change ?attr/selectableItemBackground to ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless if you need circles try both features